# Edit Video buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I need your help one more time :D
In my website I have:

```
<a href="test1.mp3" target="iframe">test 1</a>
<a href="test2.mp3" target="iframe">test 2</a>
<a href="test3.mp3" target="iframe">test 3</a>
```

When I click on url it open this song on this iframe ussing `<video>` tag.
It's possible edit video buttons? I mean, for example the style of play/pause button.
I know that it's possible but I don't know the ID of each element for edit it :D

Someone can help me?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Take a look at this website, the sources are also avalible. http://www.videojs.com/

Comment: I need to know all class as: .vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button ...

Comment: You haven't shown very much of your sources so helping is a bit hard. Show more show helping you is easier

Comment: I have no more. When I click the url with a file.mp3, it open on a iframe. If you inspect the iframe you can see '<video>' tag. It's all. I only want edit background (black default) and buttons appearance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Here is the original website:

http://nunzioweb.com/misc/movies/iframe-embed_example.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="google" value="notranslate" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Dog Smoking</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
padding-top:0;
padding-bottom:0;
padding-left:0;
padding-right:0;
margin-top:0;
margin-bottom:0;
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
}
</style>

<link href="Dogsmoke_embed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<iframe class="tscplayer_inline" name="tsc_player" src="Dogsmoke_player.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

If that doesnt work like you want you can try this:
[play iframe video on click a link javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619074/play-iframe-video-on-click-a-link-javascript)

Comment: It's not... I only want edit the Play, pause, volumen... butons. It's all.

Comment: I do not say this is the code you need. You may have to modify it a bit