# trigger a click after click element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with an `img` and an `iframe` video. I want to play the video just after click over the image. (its not valid change `url` for ux purposes)

My `js` code is not working as expected. The `youtube` video does not start.

```js
$(".youtube-video img").click(function (e) { 
  $(".youtube-video .video").trigger('click');
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="youtube-video">
    <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/<?php echo $video1 ?>/maxresdefault.jpg">
    <div class="video">
        <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $video1 ?>" allowfullscreen="" style=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by  *js code is not working as expected..*  please elaborate ?

Comment: @Swati I dont know why, but the youtube video doesnt start

Comment: here `$(".youtube-video. img")` remove that extra dot before image . Also , check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246939/start-play-embedded-iframe-youtube-video-on-click-of-an-image) post.

Comment: Its edited. Its not working.

Comment: did you check that link which i have added in my previous comment ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [play iframe video on click a link javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619074/play-iframe-video-on-click-a-link-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use `player.playVideo()` with JQuery. 
So it will be like that in javascript: `document.querySelector("iframe").contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("html5-video-player")[0].playVideo()`
The *html5-video-player* class is the class which contain the function playerVideo and we just get the iframe Dom with contentDocument. 
 And do not forget to add `?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer` at the end of the iframe's link.

From the [Youtube player api doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?csw=1#Playback_controls)

Comment: I am not using youtube api.

Comment: Yes but when you use the youtube iframe, this is adding all the functions, no script in addition of the iframe necessary. For that, you have to add ?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer

Comment: I try `$(".youtube-video .video iframe").playVideo();` but it doesnt work.

Comment: Try with the native code i give you (jquery is useless in this case)